# ImportError with Python 3

Tags: python, matplotlib, importerror

I am trying to run an example from [ThinkStats2](https://github.com/AllenDowney/ThinkStats2/tree/master/code) code. I copied everything from github - the file structure are exactly the same as given on the github.

```
chap01soln.py

from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
import sys

import nsfg
import thinkstats2


def ReadFemResp(dct_file='2002FemResp.dct',
                dat_file='2002FemResp.dat.gz',
                nrows=None):
    """Reads the NSFG respondent data.

    dct_file: string file name
    dat_file: string file name

    returns: DataFrame
    """
    dct = thinkstats2.ReadStataDct(dct_file)
    df = dct.ReadFixedWidth(dat_file, compression='gzip', nrows=nrows)
    CleanFemResp(df)
    return df


def CleanFemResp(df):
    """Recodes variables from the respondent frame.

    df: DataFrame
    """
    pass


def ValidatePregnum(resp):
    """Validate pregnum in the respondent file.

    resp: respondent DataFrame
    """
    # read the pregnancy frame
    preg = nsfg.ReadFemPreg()

    # make the map from caseid to list of pregnancy indices
    preg_map = nsfg.MakePregMap(preg)

    # iterate through the respondent pregnum series
    for index, pregnum in resp.pregnum.iteritems():
        caseid = resp.caseid[index]
        indices = preg_map[caseid]

        # check that pregnum from the respondent file equals
        # the number of records in the pregnancy file
        if len(indices) != pregnum:
            print(caseid, len(indices), pregnum)
            return False

    return True


def main(script):
    """Tests the functions in this module.

    script: string script name
    """
    resp = ReadFemResp()

    assert(len(resp) == 7643)
    assert(resp.pregnum.value_counts()[1] == 1267)
    assert(ValidatePregnum(resp))

    print('%s: All tests passed.' % script)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(*sys.argv)
```

I am getting ImportError like shown below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\wamp\www\ThinkStats_py3\chap01soln.py", line 13, in <module>
    import nsfg
  File "C:\wamp\www\ThinkStats_py3\nsfg.py", line 14, in <module>
    import thinkstats2
  File "C:\wamp\www\ThinkStats_py3\thinkstats2.py", line 34, in <module>
    import thinkplot
  File "C:\wamp\www\ThinkStats_py3\thinkplot.py", line 11, in <module>
    import matplotlib
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 105, in <module>
    import six
ImportError: No module named 'six'
```

All the files are listed under the src folder. No packages under src. I tried adding packages for nsfg and thinkstats but another error appeared. I tried upgrading python 2.7 to python 3.4. I am still getting the same error. I know I need to install the six package for matplotlib but why am I getting import error on nsfg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the import error on `nsfg` because it internally imports matplotlib (not directly, but it `imports thinkstats2` , which imports `thinkplot` which imports `matplotlib` , which has a dependency on `six` module) . And that library is not installed on your computer, so the import fails.

Most probably you do not have `six` module , you can try installing it using - `pip install six` .

Or get it from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six), unzip it and install it using - `python setup.py install`

Comment: You should also consider installing Anaconda from continuum. It has the scientific third-party libraries for python preinstalled. It'll make your life a lot easier. At least it made mine a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks Anand. I am installing all the matplotlib dependencies now and stuck on scipy which is giving an error. I hope I can get rid of all the errors once I install all the dependencies for matplotlib.

Comment: @Jslick I will try that if I still can't get scipy to install properly. Thank you.